# Is there a way to create a labeled checkbox as made in w3school example for textbox?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Looking the w3Schools Bootstrap's Input Groups examples there are `Input Groups Labels` that seems that wrap the input box 
[(here)](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_input_group_labels&stacked=h).
Is there any way to do this for `checkbox` too?

EDIT

The labels have to be inside that grey box attached to the input box (`textbox` in example case, `checkbox` in the case i want)

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what are you actually trying to achieve, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't *wrap* the input field since the closing tag comes right after the opening tag, but you can use `label` on a checkbox as well as described here in the [offical bootsrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) for forms:

Is it something like this you had in mind?

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <h2>Checkbox Group Labels</h2>
  <form>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
       <div class="form-check">
         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
       </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```